# Make YouTube api automatically start another video when first video ended

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I need to make a video page for my website which must contain a video from youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWPMSSsVdPk) and after this video ended I need to automatically display a second video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afZj1G0BIE) and the `div` with class `content`

This is my code so far:

```
<style>
  .content {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="content">
  <button>Show this button after first video ends</button>
</div>

<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
  // create youtube player
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'bWPMSSsVdPk',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
  }
  // autoplay video
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
  }
  // when video ends
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
      if(event.data === 0) {          
          alert('done');
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You could try loading a playlist with those 2 videos and having it automatically go to the second video in the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for this but it seems that the sound of the second video is also playing in the same time with the first video...

```
<style>
    .second-video {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="video-site">
  <div class="first-video">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div id="player"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-video">
    <div id="player2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
  // create youtube player
  var player;
  var player2;

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'qCDxEif_9js',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '43jHG-yH9Gc',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // autoplay video
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    $('.close').click(function(){
      $('.first-video').hide(3000);
      $('.second-video').fadeIn();
    });
  }
  // when video ends
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {
      $('.first-video').hide(3000);
      $('.second-video').fadeIn();
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way as to how one can do this with the available set of parameters that a Youtube iframe Player API has. But you can try doing this.

- Create a Playlist of the video's you want to play consecutively in the same order.
- In the REST API call set the *listType* parameter as ***playlist***.
- Retrieve the *playlistID* of that particular playlist.

  ```
  http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLPLAYLISTID
  ```
- Finally, set the ***autoplay*** parameter to 1 so that the video's in the playlist play automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
      if(event.data === 0) {          
          event.target.loadVideoById("0afZj1G0BIE");
      }
  }
```

That'll play your next video right after your first. However that also calls playVideo() which will be an issue for anyone watching on an Apple mobile device. Consider using cueVideoById() instead.