# Youtube javascript load another video when video ends

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to play another video, which I will get from my database, but I try it with some sample, which is not working at all, here is my sample code:

```
<script>

// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(id) {

    if (id == null) {var t = '0Bmhjf0rKe8';}

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: t,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {              
     // Here I want to call function again, function executes, but video will not played
       onYouTubePlayerAPIReady('yeDkcSZta2Y');
    }
}
```

There you can see, when video ends I call onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() with new video ID, it executes as well, but video do not play. I think it will be because the onPlayerReady() do not executes, or something.

How to fix this, or what change to work it properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279402/make-youtube-api-automatically-start-another-video-when-first-video-ended

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works. Call queueVideo() to load a string containing comma separated video ids of all the videos that you want to play or just one video. When there are no video left in the queue, this plays the default video '0Bmhjf0rKe8'. I never use onPlayerReady(). In fact, if I remember correctly, it was never called so I implemented using the technique shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
//
// Replaces the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;
var videosQueuedCount;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  videosQueuedCount = 1;
  var vars = {
     autoplay: 1,
     enablejsapi: 1,
     controls: 1
  }
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    playerVars: vars,
    videoId:'0Bmhjf0rKe8',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
function onPlayerReady(evt) {
}
function playVideo(VID) {
  window.top.scrollTo(0,410);
  videosQueuedCount = 1;
  player.loadVideoById(VID);
}
function queueVideo(queuedCount,VID) {
  window.top.scrollTo(0,410);
  videosQueuedCount = queuedCount;
  player.loadPlaylist(VID);
  player.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    videosQueuedCount -= 1;
    if (videosQueuedCount < 1) {
      videosQueuedCount = 1;
      playVideo('0Bmhjf0rKe8');
    }
  }
}
</script>
<div class="video-container"><div id="ytplayer"></div></div>
```